# Syntax Highlighting/Coloring for Python in Visual Studio 2019 is not working

Tags: python, visual-studio, syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-2019

I cannot get the syntax highlighting to properly work in Python with Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition. I get very basic syntax highlighting/coloring but for example the curly braces in `full = f"FirstName: {first}  LastName: {last} "` are not color coded differently from the rest of the string. I have seen this work in Visual Studio Code but I want the syntax highlighting to work in Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition. I did not install any specific plugins or extensions yet. Is there something I need to install?

Thanks

Comment: Please check you did install the Python components when you installed VS2019 (they are not in the default set of selected components).

Comment: @Richard, I did, I can edit and run Python code from within VS 2019, it is just that the syntax highlighting does not work as neatly as it shows on VS Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Visual Studio does not have support for formatted strings, so they will just appear as regular strings (it's actually a somewhat complex parsing problem to nest code and literals - I implemented it once, but it wasn't kept).

I'd recommend finding or reporting an issue on [their issue tracker](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS) to let the team know that you're interested in support.

If you're having trouble with other aspects of syntax highlighting, such as class and function names, you could also file an issue and the team will help you out.

Comment: well, the issue is not just with strings. Also the built-in `print` function is not syntax highlighted. I thought there must be an extension or an install issue that prevents my python code from being properly syntax highlighted. Syntax highlighting in PyCharm, regarding the built-in functions, works out of the box.

Comment: Built-in functions are intentionally not highlighted any differently from any other function (but if you're using Python 2.x then the print statement is highlighted as a keyword), so I think that is just different expectations rather than a product bug. 

Even so, filing a feature request for the team is a good way to let them know that you expect it to appear differently, and they can consider whether it's a worthwhile change for all users.

Comment: I switched to Pycharm for all Python development. I think VS 2019 is very ill-suited as Python IDE and VS Code has so many issues I dislike, such as no linting while typing. Pycharm underlines and points out coding errors while typing, with VS Code I need to save each time for the linter to run or otherwise turn on auto-save every few seconds which is a weird trade-off. Also, the many settings I need to initially configure just to get an acceptable Python IDE experience is a major turnoff. I love VS 2019 for C# but for Python MS is way off and has a lot  of work to make it more user friendly

Comment: I added an issue to the tracker:  https://github.com/microsoft/PTVS/issues/7024